# Update table with GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY column

Tags: sql, derby

I have a database using Derby and am trying to execute an update statement on a table that has a column with "GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY". I am not trying to update this column, but all of the others.

I can't seem to find the correct syntax to update the rest of the columns without getting errors such as "Attempt to modify an identity column".

Trying to update the table I have been using the `UPDATE` command,

```
UPDATE TableName SET Name = '...', ..., WHERE Name = '...'
```

The first value within the table is an ID field that has the `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` design and I don't want to update this value, I just want to update all of the other fields within the `UPDATE` command. I don't know how to skip updating this value or simply update the ID field with itself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What statement did you try? More details always help! Edit your question to show an actual example, with the CREATE TABLE statement that you used to create the table, and the UPDATE statement that you issued that encountered the error. And paste the actual error message into your question, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here's what I did; it worked fine. Can you identify what you are doing differently than this?

```
ij> create table t1 (a int generated by default as identity, b int);
0 rows inserted/updated/deleted
ij> insert into t1 (b) values (1);
1 row inserted/updated/deleted
ij> update t1 set b=2 where b = 1;
1 row inserted/updated/deleted
ij> select * from t1;
A          |B          
-----------------------
1          |2          
1 row selected
```